# Get nested children from parent's ID with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, nested

My table is as follows:

```
ID      Name     Parent ID
1       Joe         -
2       James       -
3       Mike        1
4       Lewis       3
5       Anne        2
6       Lucy        4
```

I'd like to get the ID of the parent and all its children. For example, if I do:

```
Select Name from Table where ID = 1 (and nested children)
```

The desired output would be:

```
Joe
Mike
Lewis
Lucy
```

Comment: This is far more advanced than SQL lesson 2.

Comment: Not looking for the correct SQL query but some guidance would be appreciated

Comment: Check out recursive cte.

Comment: @Aldridge1991 . . . Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: That was what I was looking for because SQL is not my field but I need to make a very simple exercise to automate some tasks. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It *could* be simple if you have a relatively shallow maximum depth (single digits). You could stack a bunch of outer join clauses and be done with it. If there is no maximum depth then recursive cte would be the best way to go about doing it.

Comment: There will be up to 7 nested levels so I guess I could go with your suggestion, @Igor. Nevertheless, I think it could be a good time to learn about CTE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select name, id
      from t
      where id = 1
      union all
      select t.name, t.id
      from cte join
           t
           on t.parent_id = cte.id
    )
select name
from cte;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    WITH CTE_Table AS (
      SELECT        ID, Name, Parent
      FROM            MyTable
      UNION ALL
      SELECT        MyTable.ID, MyTable.Name, MyTable.Parent
      FROM            CTE_Table INNER JOIN
                               MyTable ON CTE_Table.ID = MyTable.Parent
    )

SELECT        Name
FROM            CTE_Table
WHERE        (Parent = 1)
```

Comment: Please write ; if you use other query before use recursion like this ;WITH

Comment: I eventually end up using the answer proposed by @gordon Linoff adding distinct to avoid duplicates